# Set the subsequent two 0 after every 1 in a binary vector to 1

Tags: r, vector

I wonder how to write some simple code to solve this problem:
Question like this,I got a vector like this:

```
x <- c(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0)
```

while I want to do some computing and then get y:

```
y <- c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1)
```

The rule is :
If you find one '1',then substitue the following 2 zeros as '1'.

Comment: thank you! Iuse this to slove my question,the same idea with you but I am not familiar with diff function. x=c(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0);y <- x+c(0,x[-length(x)])+c(0,0,x[-((length(x)-1):length(x))]);
y[y>0] <-1
y

Comment: of course,you can write the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach with `shift` from `data.table`.  The `shift` can take `n` as a vector to get a `list` of `lag` (by default), `Reduce` it to a `vector` by adding (`+`) the corresponding elements of the `list`, convert to a logical vector (`> 0` - here it works without doing this) and convert to binary with `+`.

```
library(data.table)
+(Reduce(`+`, shift(x, 0:2, fill=0)) > 0)
#[1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
```

Or

```
sign(Reduce(`+`, shift(x, 0:2, fill=0)))
```

Comment: shift function saves me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

We may use

```
id <- rep(which(diff(x) == -1), each = 2) + 1:2
x[id[id <= length(x)]] <- 1
```

- `tmp <- which(diff(x) == -1)` gives positions of `1` followed by `0`;
- `id <- rep(tmp, each = 2) + 1:2` identifies the following 2 positions;
- basically we want `x[id] <- 1`, but this may create a longer vector when `x` has `1` around the end. So we bound it by: `x[id[id <= length(x)]] <- 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
sign(Reduce(function(x,y) min(3, max(x-1,0) + y), 3*x, acc=T))
```

This `Reduce()` effectively creates a counter which decrements by 1 in the case of 0, and resets to 3 in the case of 1. Taking the `sign()` gives the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

This approach uses pmax on shifted versions of the x-vector:

```
 pmax ( x, c(NA,head(x,-1)) , c(NA,NA,head(x,-2)) , na.rm=TRUE)
 [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: akrun's answer provide a shift function in data.table package,this can saves the code in pmax.